# Problems installing the French transformer model in spaCy

Tags: python, spacy

I am installing the French transformer models in spaCy and I get errors installing the French model "fr_dep_news_trf".

I tried the following methods both on the English and French transformer models and here is what I get. The English version installed for each method but the French version did not.

The only other avenue I see is importing the meta.json file but I have not found the syntax so far.

If someone has a way to solve this it would be much appreciated. I can get by but I am relatively new to Python. Sorry for the long error messages below.

Import method from command line: `python -m spacy download fr_dep_news_trf`

Error:

```
Building wheels for collected packages: sentencepiece
  Building wheel for sentencepiece (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [21 lines of output]
```

There are more errors but they are all about sentencepiece.

Import method from command line:`pip install https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/fr_dep_news_trf-3.2.0/fr_dep_news_trf-3.2.0.tar.gz`

Error:

```
cl : Command line warning D9025 : overriding '/MD' with '/MT'
      sentencepiece_wrap.cxx
      src/sentencepiece/sentencepiece_wrap.cxx(2809): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'sentencepiece_processor.h': No such file or directory
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.29.30133\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for sentencepiece
  Running setup.py clean for sentencepiece
Successfully built fr-dep-news-trf
Failed to build sentencepiece
Installing collected packages: sentencepiece, protobuf, fr-dep-news-trf
  Running setup.py install for sentencepiece ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Running setup.py install for sentencepiece did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [23 lines of output]
```

Import method from Python:

```
import spacy
spacy.cli.download("en_core_web_sm")
```

Error: The python window closed after getting to sentencepiece so I tried to run it within Viusal Studio Code and got this error after `setup(` on line 104. Again, it referred to `sentencepiece`.

```
Exception has occurred: SystemExit       (note: full exception trace is shown but execution is paused at: <module>)
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.29.30133\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:    
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
  File "C:\Users\mariejjn\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-qzfw8naf\sentencepiece_040c07904fab42a4afd6e3aa257f72da\setup.py", line 104, in <module>
    setup(
  File "<string>", line 2, in <module> (Current frame)
```

Import method from Python:

```
>>> nlp4 = Language().from_disk("E:\MyDocuments-New\LannguageModels\fr_dep_news_trf\fr_dep_news_trf-3.2.0")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\mariejjn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\spacy\language.py", line 2039, in from_disk
    util.from_disk(path, deserializers, exclude)  # type: ignore[arg-type]
  File "C:\Users\mariejjn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\spacy\util.py", line 1300, in from_disk
    reader(path / key)
  File "C:\Users\mariejjn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\spacy\language.py", line 2025, in <lambda>
    deserializers["tokenizer"] = lambda p: self.tokenizer.from_disk(  # type: ignore[union-attr]
  File "spacy\tokenizer.pyx", line 752, in spacy.tokenizer.Tokenizer.from_disk
  File "C:\Users\mariejjn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\pathlib.py", line 1117, in open
    return self._accessor.open(self, mode, buffering, encoding, errors,
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'E:\\MyDocuments-New\\LannguageModels\x0cr_dep_news_trf\x0cr_dep_news_trf-3.2.0\\tokenizer'
```

I also get an error with `nlp = nlp.from_disk("E:\MyDocuments-New\LannguageModels\fr_dep_news_trf\fr_dep_news_trf-3.2.0")`

Comment: sentencepiece is weird and has serious version problems unfortunately. Most packages using it have to pin it to a single somewhat old version. If pip is trying to build it that means it didn't find a pre-built version, which is bad - normally building packages is OK, but sentencepiece is a bit complicated. Maybe you can try an older Python version, like 3.7?

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I tried installing sentencepiece in python 3.7 and 3.9 and they both worked. Only 3.10 does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Following a tip from polm23, I tried installing sentencepiece and fr_dep_news_trf in python 3.7 and 3.9 and they both worked. Only 3.10 does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use kernel based python interpreter like conda for windows and its working fine Mac and Linux environment. Spacy is built in C language , So it may fails on sometime on latest python environments.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and read [answer]. In particular, please make sure that answers attempt to answer the question being asked. Once you have earned 50 reputation points you will be able to add comments for things like this.